# Custom Textview with seekbar getting clipped

Tags: android

I have a seekbar with a textview to show progress in %

i need it to display in this format

[image]

but when i implement it my seekbar shows as follows

[image]

The issue is the seekbar is comin on top of the textview,whereas i need it below the textview

XML for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarProgress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/slider_percentage_bg"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/custom_seekBar"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:max="100"

        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_background_selector"
        android:thumb="@drawable/slider_button"
        android:thumbOffset="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have already set marginLeft in seekBar `android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"` just remove and test it

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_seekBar"
    android:layout_width="365dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_background_selector"
    android:thumb="@drawable/slider_button"
    android:thumbOffset="0dp" />
```

Comment: doing that results in this 
http://i.imgur.com/ok1BXIl.png ,whereas i need this http://i.imgur.com/3lb2Ljw.png

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwRMp8dK9LMLN0txbkVPX2lqREk/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwRMp8dK9LMLd1dGLWlPZUk0Rms/edit

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand